# php/ssh2 script does not display the stdout to $stream

Tags: php, bash, ssh

The following php script works for simple linux commands, like ps -ef , but when i use ./dstat -t -a , it seems to hang and i dont get the prompt back on my local machine. Kep in mind that all commands are executed over ssh on a remote host:

```
<?php
$target = time() . '_' . 'txt';

if($ssh = ssh2_connect('10.1.0.174', 22)) {
    if(ssh2_auth_password($ssh, 'root', 'kmoon77')) {
        //$stream = ssh2_exec($ssh, 'whoami');
        $sCommand = 'dstat -a';
        //$sCommand = 'ps -ef';
        $stream = ssh2_exec($ssh, $sCommand);
        //$stream = ssh2_exec($ssh, 'pwd');
        stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
        $data = '';
        while($buffer = fread($stream, 4096)) {
            $data .= $buffer;
        }
        //fclose($stream);
        echo $data; // user
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Might the problem be that `dstat` just runs indefinitely?

Comment: Mario, yes that was the issue, obvious but escaped me, so i used the following command as a small sample: $sCommand = "cd /root/dstat-0.7.2 ; ./dstat -cdngy 5 3 >> test.txt"; note that we can use ; to have multiple commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for posting your root passwort.

No this is no internal amazon ip is it?

However your problem might be that the script just keeps running (or rather the command).

Try something like `fpassthru("ssh -i keyfile -l login name myserver.com dstat -a");` then you should "see" something.

Comment: that is not the real root password, and the IP ois an internal IP, not related to Amazon, or any commercial site :). Thanks for the tip though